# Creating view controller in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView`. When it finished decelerating I need to create a new instance of a `UIViewController`. The problem is that while this is created (it takes about 1 second) I can't scroll and my UI feels less fluid. I'm thinking about creating this view controller in a background thread. Is this is a good idea? I also need to do some work on it after it is created and this work must be done on the main thread. If I use dispatch_async on a method that creates the controller and then use dispath_sync (main queue) for the work I have to do on the view controller will the dispatch_sync wait until my async work is done to execute?

tl;dr I do lots of work in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating but it causes my scrollview to have poor scroll performance. How can I improve the performance?

Sample:

```
- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating {
    dispatch_async(background) {
         [self createVC];
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:(setupView)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can dispatch_async to create your UIViewController, and when you are done creating your view controller use performSelectorOnMainThread to perform your operations on mainthread and adding your view controller to your scrollView.

Comment: I've added a sample to the question. Would it work?

Comment: IT shoudld useaully be like this 
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setupView) withObject:(id) waitUntilDone:YES/NO]; 
YES/NO depends on your requirement.

Comment: @Priyatham51 Yeh, I get that, I was just writing some pseudocode :) I will try it and if it works will mark it as the answer.

Comment: This is quite a badass idea. Facebook wrote the whole library for that shit https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit. UIKit docs state that all UI shit should happen on main thread, so I wouldn't be surprised if suddenly things go south in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Need some more code yo see why did your scrollView is stopping while you initiate UIVIewController, but by the way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    // This is happening in the background thread.
    // create view controller
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // This is happening on the main thread; all UI updates must happen here.
        // here setup view
    });
});
```

And also you can create ViewController when you init your scrollView and save it in local variable, and when it's decelerating, then just setup your view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dispatch_async to create your UIViewController, and when you are done creating your view controller use performSelectorOnMainThread to perform your operations on mainthread and adding your view controller to your scrollView.

Use performSelectorOnMainThread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setupView) withObject:(id) waitUntilDone:YES/NO];
```

YES/NO depends on your requirement